# How to get an individual css style in pyquery

Tags: python, css, pyquery

You can **set** a css style using several methods:

```
p = PyQuery('<p></p>')
p.css('font-size','16px')
p.css(['font-size'] = '16px'
p.css = {'font-size':'16px'}
```

Great, but how to **get** an **individual** css style?

```
p.css('font-size') # jquery-like method doesn't work
[<p>]
p.css['font-size'] # pythonic method doesn't work!
[<p>]
p.css.font_size # BeardedO's suggestion.
[<p>]
p.attr('style')    # too much information.
'font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold'
```

This seems strange, inconvenient and unpyquery and unpython like!  One of the first two ought to return the style text, surely?

Is there a way to get a single css style alone without resorting to tools like split()?

Answer (score 1):

p.css.font_size

Does this work?

Comment: I was really hoping the underscore would fix it :(.

Comment: perhaps p.css('fontSize') might work? The camel case style works in jQuery, perhaps it will work here.

Comment: That didn't work either.  I looked into the pyquery code and it just returns self.  Maybe I should contact the author about the matter.  Is it worth sending him the code I added to get css() to return the value?

Comment: I didn't send it to him.  I just ended up writing a simple function to return the css value by using split() on attr('css') and grabbing the appropriate value.  I figure a lot of these packages are in a state of flux, what with python 3 coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and convert it into a dict.

Comment: Great idea! Here's a probably too long list comprehension to do that: `dict((name.strip(), val.strip()) for name, val in (pair.split(':') for pair in pq.attr('style').split(';')))` where `p` is an instance of `PyQuery`

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your comment that you have already figured this out, but PyQuery does not provide this functionality.

The `css` method (line 824 in pyquery.py) only sets attributes and cannot retrieve, which *is* a shame. Although, given that PyQuery is not working with a stylesheet, the utility of retrieving CSS is limited anyway.

Manually sorting through the results of `p.attr(style)` seems to be the best way to go at the moment. I would like to see an option for retrieving css values if only one argument is passed to the `css` method, but we shall see.